# Django consume REST API from 3rd party

Tags: django, rest

I am building a Django site that will consume a 3rd party's REST API and pull its XML data into the site. Is there a tutorial on how to do this in Django. I am fine with a high level overview of the wheres and hows of the steps involved. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out Python's [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library.

Comment: Thanks. But I am not clear on where and how to use them - the flow. For example, how to write the models, views, dir structure - I am familiar with the basics - writing models, views, etc. but haven't worked with a complex project yet - like one that consumes REST services.

Comment: I think you'd be well served by reading a book or taking a course on API consumption. Frankly, it's a topic that's beyond the purview of an answer on Stack Overflow, IMO.

Comment: I understand. Foound [this](http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/integrate_web_apis_into_your_django_site/) and it seems helpful.